# primefaces global filter without the column filters

Tags: javascript, filter, datatable, primefaces

I'm working on the example mentioned in primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml). I am trying to create a global filter for the datatable.
Currently the table looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is remove the individual column filters and have only the global filter.
Like this:
[image]
To do that I remove the `filterBy` attribute on the column definitions. But on doing that, I get a javascript warning - `Error in parsing value for`filter`, declaration dropped` and the global filter doesn't work.

Could someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure you have the `filterBy="#{myRowVar.sonmeField}"` in every `p:column` (because the global filter needs it)

And also add the `filterStyle="display:none"` in every `p:column` (adding of `filterStyle="display:none"` will make it not visible...)

Comment: Yes, I was about to add this in the comment. Thanks though :). I do have another problem. I'm trying to use lazy loading with the global filter. But as soon as I select number of records from the dropdown, it shows `No Records Found` since global filter is not present in the filter map in the load method on the server side. Do you know any workaround for this? Would be of great help...

Comment: I'm not sure how the filter affects your lazy loading... ? without the filter the lazy loading works fine ?

Comment: yes and with the column filters too it works fine but the global filter doesn't work

Comment: ok the latest primefaces release does add the globalfilter in the map, so it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

or you can just put:

```
.ui-column-filter{
     display: none !important;
}
```

in your .css to hide all column filters