# Data Table filter on Prime faces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have code below form. . i wanted to search globally. please suggest me how can i do it

```
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{employeeCategoryBean.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{employeeCategoryBean.onRowSelect}" />

            <f:facet name="header">  
                      <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="modelTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>  
                </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                    #{model.name}
                </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Prefix">
                    #{model.prefix}
                </p:column>
```

Comment: do you want this? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

Comment: I think @Uday wants this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10702116/617373

Comment: @Daniel i hav follwed that link also but is not working.  could u send complete code

Comment: add `filterBy` to your columns just like in showcase, than try, if wont work post your complete code in your question.

Comment: @ Daniel, i used filterBy attribute also but it wont work. i have posted the complete code. .check out and let me know .

Comment: @Daniel  it is not working.  anyway Thanks for response.

Comment: Checkout the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701841/primefaces-global-filter-without-the-column-filters/10702116#10702116

Answer (score 0):

All is on the primefaces page

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf