# columns height wont set when resizable filtering are enabled

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I had a requirement to remove the filter inputs from my filtering enabled datatable.

I've managed to followe the workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701841/primefaces-global-filter-without-the-column-filters) but i cant manage to change the columns height.
I've tried all possible CSS on my columns with the help of Chrome DevTools yet no avail.

```
<p:column filterBy="#{column.dbname}"
          filterStyle="display:none"
          headerText="#{column.userListname}"
          style="#{column.visible==true? 'height:15px!important':'display:none!important;'}"
          width="#{column.visible==true? 13:0}"
          resizable="#{column.visible==true? column.resizable:false}">
```

Here is the image after `filterStyle="display:none"` :

[image: screenshot taken after adding global filter]

and this is the desired result (of course with the global filter):

[image: screenshot taken before adding global filter]

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem tampering with table at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf but after applying "display: none;" to ".ui-datatable .ui-column=filter" in browser I get result as in your second image. Does it work also in your case when you only change styles in browser (not in code)?

Comment: you're correct I've tried the same thing and it works just fine,this is bizarre probably because i have a resizable and draggable enabled datatble, what do you think ?

Comment: I've just tested it with draggable=true and resizable=false datatable and it works just fine.

Comment: the problem is i need to keep the datatable columns resizable